# Extract array variable using regex with particular text within

Tags: regex

This is my search string:

```
abc[0] = xyz[(3/*my-const:VECT_E->_numget_C*/)];
```

and I wrote this regex pattern:

```
(?<=)(\w*)(?=\[)
```

but this is matching to "abc" and I want to extract the array variable which has the commented code within "/*my-const....". So the output expect as xyz than abc.

Please check if I made any mistake in the regex.

Comment: So use `(?<=\s)\w+(?=\[)` or `(?!^)\b\w+(?=\[)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\s)\w+(?=\[)
(?!^)\b\w+(?=\[)
```

See [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/GqvAj6/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqvAj6/2).

*Details*

- `(?<=\s)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a whitespace to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?!^)\b` - a location not at the start of string, but at the word boundary (the next char is a word char, so the char right before cannot be a word char)
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=\[)` - a positive  lookahead that requires a `[` char to appear immediately to the right of the current location.